# How do I use html in Template directive in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, onclick

Currently I want to have a clickable anchor tag in template to display a message. However, during run time, I keep receiving this error.

*Uncaught ReferenceError: display is not defined*

My code is as followed:

```
prepareKendoGrid(searchresults:any[]) {
    console.log(this.searchresults);

    this.adhocSearchKendoGrid = {
        sortable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "filename",
            title: " ",
            width: 50,
            template: "#if(filetype == 'xml') {#<i style='margin-left:10px' class='fa fa-file-code-o fa-1x'></i>#} else if(filetype == 'doc') {#<i style='margin-left:10px' class='fa fa-file-word-o fa-1x'></i>#} else if(filetype == 'pdf') {#<i style='margin-left:10px' class='fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-1x'></i>#}else if(filetype == 'txt') {#<i style='margin-left:10px' class='fa fa-file-text-o fa-1x'></i>#}#"
        },
        {
            field: "filename",
            title: "File Name",
            width: 200
        },
        {
            field: "content",
            title: "Content"
        },
        {
            field: "start_time",
            title: "Conversation Date",
            width: 200
        },
        {
            field: "attachments.count",
            title: "Attachments",
            width: 100,
            template: "<a style='margin-right:10px' (click)='display()'><i class='fa fa-paperclip fa-fw'></i></a>#: attachments.count #"
        }],
        dataSource: searchresults
    };

    let cst = new CSTGridComponent();
    cst.createGrid(this.adhocSearchKendoGridId,this.adhocSearchKendoGrid);
}

display() {

    console.log('ok');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
(click)='display()'
```

See also

- http://learnangular2.com/events/

Comment: Unfortunately when I do that, nothing happens. Is there a reason why it's like that or is it because in the template directive, it does not find such a method?

Comment: I didn't look to closely at your other code but what I see doesn't make much sense (except the `tempalte: ...` line) What is that supposed to do? Where do you have this code? Can you add more code to your question to make it more clear what you try to accomplish?

Comment: You should use `*ngFor`. Angular2 doesn't care about HTML added dynamically. It only processes HTML added statically to a components template.

Comment: But in this case, each row has an icon and ngFor wouldn't be needed here. Is there a way to still allow the icon to be clickable and linked to the display() function?

Comment: Difficulat because the click would then not be handled by Angular. "ngFor wouldn't be needed here" sounds weird. `*ngFor` is not heavy. In Angular2 you should strive to let Angular2 update the DOM and in your code only update the data and let `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, `*ngSwitchCase`, `[]`, {{}}` update the DOM.

Comment: That's a good point! Appreciate your help on this. Will try to work with what you have said.

Comment: I have tried using *ngFor inside template, but it doesn't output the data accordingly. In fact, it prints '{{values}}' when i was to display an array of values.

Comment: As mentioned above. Angular doesn't care about HTML added dynamically. `(click)="xxx"` and `{{yyy}}` and `[prop]="val"` won't do anything if they are not added statically to a components template. If you really need to add it dynamically you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960